# Adding YouTube-compatible chapter marks to video (using console tools)

Tags: linux, video-conversion, youtube

I've created an mp4 video file that I want to upload to YouTube. The video gets correctly processed by YT. Because it's a long video, I'd like to add chapter marks to allow skipping ahead to specific time positions, making sure that whatever I do gets recognized by YT as valid chapter marks.

How can I do that on Linux?

Comment: As a workaround, it is possible to add timestamps to the description, as per https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/youtube/JtP62BHEGP4